# Why do drand48() and srand48(int seed) have the numbers 48 in their names?

Tags: c, random

I was using these functions and just wondering; why do they have a 48 at the end of them? I tried to search a bit but couldn't seem to find anything. Is it something mathematical or historical?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the manual page of `srand48(3)`:

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> These functions generate pseudo-random numbers using the linear congruential algorithm and 48-bit integer arithmetic.
>
> [...]
>
> All the functions work by generating a sequence of 48-bit integers, Xi, according  to  the linear congruential formula:
>
> Xn+1 = (aXn + c) mod m, where n >= 0
>
> The parameter m = 2^48, hence 48-bit integer arithmetic is performed.